# ASP routing vs relative links

Tags: asp.net, relative-path, asp.net-routing

I'm trying to implement routing on a simple site using web forms 3.5 SP1. The problem is that the site is using a simple form of CMS, so the user can create html content and add images. 
Since all the 'articles' in the database are stored with the image urls relative to the Default.aspx and my route is idCat/*categoryPath, all the images now appear broken.

I guess I could parse all the src and href attributes in the articles on the fly, but I'm hoping for a better solution...

Comment: Poor explanation. Please give more detail and what CMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In most WYSIWYG editors there is a configuration value to set the full path for uploaded images.

UPDATE: For you comment, [ckEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)! It is much more robust and has the option I have mentioned.

Comment: I'm using HtmlEditor from Ajax Control Toolkit? Could you suggest better?